# Will this click the link when the keys are pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, so I need to create the code to ensure that when certain keys are pressed triggers the event as if a button were clicked. following the link through that button when they keyboard keys are pressed.

```
el.on('keypress', function(event){
    $('li').find('li.next');
        if (keycode == 39) {
            $('.next').click();
        }

});
el.on('keypress', function(event){
   $('li').find('li.prev');
        if (keycode == 37){
            $('.prev').click();

    }
});
```

Comment: if you want to trigger the click use $('.next').trigger('click');

Comment: what's the point of this line: `$('li').find('li.prev');` it doesn't seem to do anything.  Also why don't you just try it to see if it works?

Comment: What is `el`? Where is the corresponding html? What link are you talking about .. `<li>` is not a link. Please show all relevant html structure. Using `find()` looks very suspicious.

Comment: basically, I have a next and a previous button in modals which I want to trigger when a user presses the right and left arrow key,

Comment: @charlietfl

var el = this.element;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS

```
el.on('keyup', function (event) {
var $paginationList = el.find('ul.pagination');
const LeftKeyCode = 37;
const RightKeyCode = 39;
var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
if (keyCode == LeftKeyCode){
    $paginationList.find('li.prev').find('a').click();
}
if (keyCode == RightKeyCode){
    $paginationList.find('li.next').find('a').click();
}
```

HTML

```
<li class="prev">
           <a href="<?= $pageUrl ?>" class="widget-modal-drilldown"> Previous</a>
        </li>
<li class="next">
            <a href="<?= $pageUrl ?>" class="widget-modal-drilldown">Next</a>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the Hotkeys library for binding key events

https://github.com/tzuryby/jquery.hotkeys